# PyQt5: Slot in separate file not being called

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals, qt-slot

I currently have a basic GUI right now with each page in its own file. I can navigate to and from each page with no problem, but I'm having difficulty simply passing a search query to another Widget. Here's where I setup the connections in the main file:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import search
import watching
import helpinfo
import results

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.centralWidget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.startScreen = Start(self)
        self.searchScreen = search.Search(self)
        self.watchingScreen = watching.Watching(self)
        self.helpInfoScreen = helpinfo.HelpInfo(self)
        self.resultsScreen = results.Results(self)
        self.centralWidget.addWidget(self.startScreen)
        self.centralWidget.addWidget(self.searchScreen)
        self.centralWidget.addWidget(self.watchingScreen)
        self.centralWidget.addWidget(self.helpInfoScreen)
        self.centralWidget.addWidget(self.resultsScreen)
        self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.startScreen)

        self.startScreen.searchClicked.connect(lambda: self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.searchScreen))
        self.startScreen.watchingClicked.connect(lambda: self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.watchingScreen))
        self.startScreen.helpInfoClicked.connect(lambda: self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.helpInfoScreen))

        self.searchScreen.searchSubmitted.connect(lambda: self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.resultsScreen))
        self.searchScreen.passQuery.connect(lambda: self.resultsScreen.grabSearch) #This is the problem line

        self.searchScreen.clicked.connect(lambda: self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.startScreen))
        self.watchingScreen.clicked.connect(lambda: self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.startScreen))
        self.helpInfoScreen.clicked.connect(lambda: self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.startScreen))
        self.resultsScreen.clicked.connect(lambda: self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.startScreen))
```

Here's the search file:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Search(QWidget):

    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    searchSubmitted = pyqtSignal()
    passQuery = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Search, self).__init__(parent)

        logo = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('res/logo.png')
        logo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        logo.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        logo.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)

        label = QLabel(text="This is the search page.")
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        button = QPushButton(text='Submit')
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.submitSearch())
        button2 = QPushButton(text='Go back.')
        button2.clicked.connect(self.clicked.emit)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()        
        layout.addWidget(logo)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.textbox)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(button2)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def submitSearch(self):
        self.searchSubmitted.emit()
        self.passQuery.emit(self.textbox.text())
```

And here is the results file:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Results(QWidget):

    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Results, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create Logo
        logo = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('res/logo.png')
        logo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        logo.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        logo.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)


        # Create page contents
        label = QLabel(text="This is the results page. If you see this, it's still broken.")
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        button = QPushButton(text='Add to watching.')
        button2 = QPushButton(text='Go back.')
        button2.clicked.connect(self.clicked.emit)

        # Set up layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(logo)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(button2)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def grabSearch(self, str):
        print(str)
        self.label.setText(str)
```

The way I understand it, what I have right now should be working. When the user submits some text on the search page, it calls the submitSearch() function. That function emits two signals: the first, searchSubmitted, changes the screen to the results screen (this works as intended). The second, passQuery, should be passing the contents of the textbox to the connected function grabSearch() in the results file. However, the passQuery never seems to be caught by the results page despite being connected. I've verified with print statements that it *is* being emitted, but that's it.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:

- If you are going to use a lambda to make the connection you must invoke the function with the arguments.

---

```
self.searchScreen.passQuery.connect(lambda text: self.resultsScreen.grabSearch(text))
```

But it is better to use the direct connection since the signatures are the same:

```
self.searchScreen.passQuery.connect(self.resultsScreen.grabSearch)
```

- Another error is that the results.py label must be a member of the class:

  ```
  self.label = QLabel(text="This is the results page. If you see this, it's still broken.") # <-- 
  self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) # <--
  # ..

  # Set up layout
  layout = QVBoxLayout()
  layout.addWidget(logo)
  layout.addWidget(self.label) # <--
  ```
- And finally do not use reserved words like `str`, change to:

  ```
  @pyqtSlot(str)
  def grabSearch(self, text):
      self.label.setText(text)
  ```